# I cannot use RestSharp In my WixSharp installer, is it possible to accomplish this with HttpClient or WebClient?

Tags: c#, asp.net, rest, webclient, restsharp

```
private async Task<AuthenticationToken> GetToken()
    {

        string username = loginDialog.username;
        string password = loginDialog.password;
        string requestString = $"Service/Login";
        RestRequest request = new RestRequest(requestString, Method.POST);
        request.AddParameter("username", username);
        request.AddParameter("password", password);
        IRestResponse<AuthenticationToken> response = await _client.ExecuteAsync<AuthenticationToken>(request);
        return response.Data;
    }
```

I am using RestSharp in a few projects within my solution.  I can not use it within the installer, WixSharp isn't working well with RestSharp.  I need to use WebClient or HttpClient to achieve the same response as I get with this Method using the RestSharp library.  Is anyone able to help?

Comment: Use `HttpClient`, `WebClient` is depricated/legacy/obsolete.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the case of requirement some external assembly for Wixsharm runtime just add it like below:

```
var proj = ManagedProject()
proj.DefaultRefAssemblies.Add("Restsharp.dll")
```

And it will be avaliable for load in runtime and accessable for use.

P.S. Dont forget to check assembly existence in your builder executable file output location.

Comment: This was great help! Thank you @Sergey

Comment: Where would I put this @Sergey

Comment: @AndrewLazare This property avaliable in *ManagedProject* project class, you should use it if you in real use WixSharp. If my post will help to you please mark it as answer after check. Thanks

Comment: It was very helpful. I think I have figured it out...I just didnt know where to put it within the Program.cs.  Sorry about not hitting the check. New to posting on Stack!

Comment: @AndrewLazare Could you please post your Program.cs? Does it contains *ManagedProject* class usage? Or send it to xyliman[at]gmail mail.

Comment: I am trying to post it.  How can i add a block of code within this comment section.  Everything I have read is not working?

Answer (score 0):

Sure, try this

```
var httpClient = new HttpClient();
var headers = httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders;
headers.Add("Content-Tpye", "application/form-url-encoded");
string requestParams = string.Format("grant_type=password&username={0}&password={1}", username, password);
HttpContent content = new StringContent(requestParams);
var response = httpClient.PostAsync(requestString, content);
var responseContent = await response.Result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
```

Then you can use JSON deserializer on `responseContent` using `NewtonSoft` or any JSON library.

Comment: var token = JsonSerializer.Serialize(responseContent);            @MohtishamZubair                   Like this? And what would I return? Thank you so much for your help. I am still new.